# htaccess redirect dynamic URL to another dynamic URL

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect one dynamic URL to another, but with slightly changed parameters. This is the original URL:

```
http://www.EXAMPLE.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=5
```

and it needs to be redirected to

```
http://www.EXAMPLE.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=25
```

I have tried so many different variations, but not one seemed to work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^main_page=index&cPath=5$
RewriteRule ^/(index\.php|)$ http://www.EXAMPLE.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=25 [L,R=301]
```

I'm going crazy with this... Can anyone please point me in the right direction and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe leading slash is the problem in your pattern. Try this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^main_page=index&cPath=5$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(index\.php)?$ /$1?main_page=index&cPath=25 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: aaaah, such a beautiful solution, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe without condition?

```
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^index.php?main_page=index&cPath=5$ http://www.EXAMPLE.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=25 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: QUERY_STRING is not available in RewriteRule, because RewriteRule deals with the path, so RewriteCond should be used.